# Find complete list of members for Excel VBA forms button objects

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

In Excel 2010, using VBA code to create a macro-calling push-button.

NOTE: This is really a question about where to find documentary support for a type of object, not a coding thing as such.

So... Working from the macro recorder, I get this (supposing I want to turn cell M8 into a button):

```
Sub MakeMyButton()

    ' Some basic definitions
    StarterRow = 8
    MyLeft = Cells(StarterRow, "M").Left
    MyTop = Cells(StarterRow, "M").Top
    MyHeight = Cells(StarterRow, "M").Height
    MyWidth = Cells(StarterRow, "M").Width

    ' Now comes the creation bit        
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(MyLeft, MyTop, MyWidth, MyHeight).Select
    With Selection
        .AltText = "View"
        .OnAction = "afRoomText"
        ' .Value = xlOff
        ' .LinkedCell = "M" & StarterRow
        ' .Display3DShading = True
    End With
End Sub
```

The problem is, of course, that .Value and .LinkedCell and .Display3DShading, here marked as remarks, are not valid for Buttons.Add -- fair enough. But I cannot seem to find a comprehensive list of what IS valid for this object! Anyone know where to look?

(Incidentally, how come the record-macro thing uses things like "CheckBoxes.Add" that aren't documented anywhere obvious in Excel VBA? If you go hunting for "CheckBoxes" in the documentation, you find a lot of tangential remarks but no actual information, as though this were deprecated code that just happens to be used automatically....)

Comment: Change the options of your VBE to force `Option Explicit` !

Answer (score 2):

Always declare all your variables using `Dim`. For objects (such as `Button`) this will give you access to autocompletion. Example:

```
Dim b As Button ' Aha!
Set b = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(324, 102, 108, 51)
```

[image: Autocompletion for Button object]

Another way to create a button:

```
Dim but As Shape
Dim sh As Worksheet

Set sh = ActiveSheet
Set but = sh.Shapes.AddFormControl(xlButtonControl, 100, 100, 100, 100)

With but
    .AlternativeText = "View"
    .OnAction = "afRoomText"
    With .TextFrame
        .Characters.Text = "Press Me"
        .Characters.Font.Color = RGB(255, 50, 50)
    End With
End With
```

Comment: ++ good answer. Also you can select the `b` and hit F1 and it most of the time takes you to the developer reference. Also if you are working with classes it's worth hitting F2 and finding class properties via Object Browser.